# Getting a call Vs pressing home

Tags: android

I run my android app, and when I press home button and come back to the app. Everything is maintained (the score, the state ..etc).  assume it goes to OnPause the OnResume.

However, when  I get a phone call while running my app, then my app state is reset (score is gone ..etc).

Why is that? Shouldn't it go through the onPause/OnResume as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a phone call, it does go through `onPause` and `onStop` and when it is brought to the front again it goes through `onStart` and `onResume`.  It may also be going through `onDestroy` which will cause it to go through `onCreate` when you bring it back.  Suggest putting `Log` statements in each of the lifecycle methods to see which are getting called (or breakpoints in the debugger).  Then you'll know what approach to take to resume your game.

In reality, you should implement the app such that it can go through `onDestroy` and recover when starting up again in the way you want.

Comment: indeed, shared preferences or some static file might help

Comment: I like the idea of logging, I totally forgot that. Plus thanks for the explanation.I will accept it (unless I get a better definit answer)

Answer (score 2):

When your app goes into the background, the Android OS decides if it should kill the app based upon current factors (e.g. available memory). If there are insuffuicient resources to maintain an app in the `onPaused()` state then they are destroyed (`onStop()` followed by `onDestroy()`).

> Shouldn't it go through the onPause/OnResume as well?

Based upon the above and [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), then yes it does go into `onPause` but then it goes into the other phases afterward.

Here is a handy image to help from the documentation that i *know* you read.

[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I pressed Home many times and opened a lot of apps , my app never got destroyed. Only  when I receive a phone call. I like your answer but I wish there was a suggestion +1 though